# Disable dynamic font size on alert message

Tags: ios, react-native

Is there a way to disable dynamic font scaling for alert messages in react native, like on simple text when you use allowFontScaling={false}? Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It can not just because of Alert in iOS is provided by operating system. Is a external tool for the app.

Anyway you can create your own Alerts by using Modal component  that they are modificables like you want, inserting your own components inside.

See Modal component here:

[Modal documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal)